# How to change subfolder wordpress url to root of domain name?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system

I have a WordPress website located at subfolder `wp` at `https://example.com/wp`.

in `https://example.com` I have an `index.php` file where I want to write custom HTML without using WordPress library at all.

**My Question,** How to change WordPress URL like below:

original:

```
https://example.com/wp/blog-post-123
```

expected:

```
https://example.com/blog-post-123
```

Comment: Well, you obviously can write simple internal rewriting rules to map the desired URLs onto the actual ones. Nothing keeps you from doing that. The only challenge here: you either need to do that for _all_ such wp based URLs, or you need to have some aspect by which the rewriting engine can decide whether to rewrite an incoming request to that wordpress logic or not. Which usually is the path component. If you eliminate you need to point out something else. What should that be? You need _something_ ...

Comment: Why would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to configure your WordPress permalinks to exclude the `/wp` subdirectory.

> in `https://example.com` I have an `index.php` file where I want to write custom HTML without using WordPress library at all.

Assuming you request `/index.php` directly in the root and this references no external resources (images, CSS, JS etc.) then in your root `/.htaccess` file you rewrite all requests that don't match the specific URL `/index.php` to the `/wp` subdirectory.

For example:

```
# /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests other than `/index.php` to the /wp WordPress directory
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ wp/ [L]
```

This still allows the WordPress *homepage* be accessible via the root URL `/` (which is rewritten to the `/wp/` subdirectory).

Then in your `/wp/.htaccess` file you have the WordPress front-controller.

For example:

```
# /wp/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any direct requests for the subdirectory back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The first redirect is really only necessary if you are changing an existing URL structure and moving from `/wp/<wordpress-url>` to `/<wordpress-url>`. Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Clear your browser cache before testing.

---

#### If non-WordPress `/index.php` file should be accessible by `/`

However, if you want the non-WordPress `/index.php` file to be accessible by simply requesting the root directory `/` (and using mod_dir to serve the `DirectoryIndex`) then this creates an ambiguity since you have a single URL (ie. `/`) that is expected to serve two different pages: `/index.php` (the non-WordPress file in the root) and `/wp/index.php` (the WordPress front-controller / homepage) - which is clearly not possible. In this case the WordPress "homepage" will not be accessible, unless you allow requests for `/index.php` to be rewritten to `/wp/` (but that is arguably "backward" and introduces additional complexity so is not be recommended).

If this is the case then you need to change the root `/.htaccess` file to the following in order to rewrite any requests other than `/` (or `/index.php`) to the `/wp` subdirectory.

```
# /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests other than `/index.php` to the /wp WordPress directory
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ wp/ [L]
```

Requests to `/` or `/index.php` access `/index.php` in the root, everything else is rewritten to the `/wp` subdirectory. The WordPress *homepage* is no longer accessible.

Use the same `/wp/.htaccess` file as stated above.

---

#### If non-WordPress `/index.php` file uses external resources

If your root `/index.php` file also references other external resources (images, CSS, JavaScript, etc.) then you need to modify the root `/.htaccess` file to rewrite all requests that don't match actual files (or directories) to the `/wp` subdirectory.

For example:

```
# /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests that don't map to actual files to the /wp WordPress directory
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . wp/ [L]
```

Again, use the same `/wp/.htaccess` file as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

In the case, you can rename your custom index.php to something else like home.php, and install WordPress in the root directory.
After that change the DirectoryIndex in .htaccess file if you are using Apache.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex home.php index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

So when you visit  https://example.com, home.php will be rendered, but if you access  https://example.com/subpage WordPress will handle it.